# Add #tab-something to onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href

Tags: javascript, tabs

I need to add #tab-something to the URL with onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href or anything else, that will provide me with the following:

If the present URL is .../product_id=49 I want when clicked on a particular link at that same page, the page to refresh and the URL to become .../product_id=49#tab-something

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the working code:

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-askquestion\']').trigger('click');">
```

Any chance to make it scroll down to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
window.location.href = "#tab-something";
```

Edit:
Reading your code, this maybe solve your problem:

```
onClick="window.location.href=this.href;window.location.reload();"
```

had not understood that it was necessary to refresh the page.

Comment: Doesn't work, or I don't know how to implement it :) I edited the first post, so see the full code, and if you can paste me the full code with changes, it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Nope, the edit's not working as well. It doesn't reload the page :(

Comment: tip: `return false;` after the reload, will prevent href= effect by `a` tag.

Comment: Any idea in the edited code how to put #tab-something ? Because I edited my first code, and now it doesn't containt the #tab-something, so I will need it to put it in your code, I think that might solve the problem...

Comment: `onClick="window.location.href='#tab-something';window.location.reload();"` works here, in firefox.

Comment: It's kind a working, but not the way I imagined :) It opens the #tab-something, but it's not scrolling down to it. If I manually put the link in the address bar like this: .../product_id=49#tab-something it opens the #tab-something and scrolls down to it...

Comment: So, any suggestion how can I make this thing work? Open the #tab-something and scroll down to it?

Comment: you already had a `<a name="tab-something"></a>` on target position?

Comment: I used this code: <a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-something\']').trigger('click');"> and now it's ok. But is there any chance to scroll down to #tab-something ? Because this way it only opens it, not scrolling down to it...